# Why is it hard to implement fast network transfer of small files?

Tags: networking, file-io, linux-kernel, filesystems

I use some kinds of network mounts (like Samba Windows shares, sshfs, scp) on different networks (LAN, Dialup). Whenever it comes to transferring a large amount of small files, I see poor performance. Far away from what would theoretically be possible. No resource appears really busy, so it seems to be a question about the software behind that (this is why I'm hopefully not OT here).

What is the problem from a software developer perspective behind that? Why do those tools not saturate any component of my system or the network?

Is that just because the Linux kernel makes some stuff complicated, or is there more to know about?

Comment: Use `tar` or `rsync`. Would be much faster.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/344534/why-does-copying-the-same-amount-of-data-take-longer-if-spread-across-many-separ/344860#344860  IOW copy from a ramdisk to another ramdisk to minimize filesystem overhead and to gauge the transfer overhead of the network.